# Created class is not appearing in other class files asp.net/visual basic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Very basic explanation: I have created a "User" class in a `ConnectionClass.cs` file and need to use it elsewhere (see below, it's a login button).

The code I'm trying to type is: `

```
   namespace Vehicle_Website.Pages.Account

{

    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {      
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //Store login variables to session
                Session["login"] = user.Name;
                Session["type"] = user.Type;

                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Login Failed";
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

The "User" should be highlighting in "blue" if you like, recognizing that it's an already created class elsewhere, except is isn't and I' getting an error

> "type or namespace "User" could not be found"

The exact same applies to the "ConnectionClass" line.. It should be highlighting but again says not recognized.

I have created a `public class User` and a `public static User LoginUser(string login, string password)` elsewhere and they work fine without errors. I cant understand why, in plain English, the words "User" and "ConnectionClass" are not "highlighting/changing colour" and being recognised.

I have tried changing properties to compile but seems to have done nothing.

Whatever other information you need I'll be happy to share.

UPDATE***

This is my `ConnectionClass.cs` file (which is working fine):

```
namespace Vehicle_Website.App_Code
{
    public static class ConnectionClass
    {
        private static SqlConnection conn;
        private static SqlCommand command;


        static ConnectionClass()
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ToString();
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("", conn);

        }

        public static User LoginUser(string login, string password)
        {
            //Check if user exists
            string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM WebsiteDB.dbo.users WHERE name = '{0}'", login);
            command.CommandText = query;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                if(amountOfUsers == 1)
                {
                    //User exists, check if passwords match
                    query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", login);
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    if(dbPassword == password)
                        {
                        //Passwords match, retrieve further information.
                        query = string.Format("SELECT email, user_type FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", login);
                        command.CommandText = query;

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        User user = null;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string email = reader.GetString(0);
                            string type = reader.GetString(1);

                            user = new User(login, password, email, type);
                        }
                        return user;
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        //Passwords do not match.
                        return null; 
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //User exists
                    return null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So i think i may have found the problem but no idea how to fix:

Basically my login.aspx.cs page isnt being "linked" to my ConnectionClass.cs

By this, i mean, I have created the below line on the login.aspx.cs page :

```
 Session["login"] = user.Name;
```

When i try and use `".Name"` on my ConnectionClass.cs file, it isnt recognised : 
user.Name);

Any idea on how to ensure both pages are communicating? I have tried correcting the namespace so they both match with no luck...

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Aravind Error is on both the "User" and "ConnectionClass" 

First is "the type or namespace "User" Could not be found
Second is "The name "ConnectionClass" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: please update the post with the class definition of **ConnectionClass** completely with the namespace

Comment: pls check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your ConnectionClass in the same project as the login button? If not you have to add a reference to the project that contains the ConnectionClass.

Also, is your ConnectionClass static? If it is not you will not be able to use it without creating first an instance of a class like this:

```
ConnectionClass myClass = new ConnectionClass();
User user = myClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: ConnectionClass is static, and it is the same project, I have it like this : `public static class ConnectionClass { private static SqlConnection conn; private static SqlCommand command; static ConnectionClass() { string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ToS‌​tring(); conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); command = new SqlCommand("", conn); }` 
The button is on the my login page,( after i double click the login button i am entering the above code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full name of the class . That is ConnectedClass.User when accessing the nested class. By default nested class is private so also make sure you are using the correct access modifier

Comment: Hey, do you mean here: 
`User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);`

If so, "LoginUser" is the ConnectionClass I beleive i need to use, Im expecting the "User" and "ConnectionClass" to be acknowledged but they aren't. 

I have tried changing it too .User but just getting a build error.... Change it back to what i have and im still getting The name ConnectionClass cannot be found.

Thanks!!

Comment: ConnectionClass.User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);

Comment: Yeah tried like that, nothing happens except now both ConnectionClass words highlight with error **("the type or namespace does not be found")** ... I have updated question with connectionclass info.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. See to that the namespace **Vehicle_Website.App_Code** is included
   in the **aspx.cs** which contains the button click method
2. Clearly see this line

   ```
   public static class ConnectionClass
   ```

   As per the code it is a static class and also see this constructor!

   ```
   static ConnectionClass()
   {
       string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ToString();
       conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       command = new SqlCommand("", conn);

   }
   ```

   When is the constructor called during instanciating an object.  Is
       it possible instanciate the ConnectionClass?    As per OOPs
       programming concepts, you cannot do it. Then how will the connection
       string and command will be assigned!!

   ### Try fixing this first.

Comment: When you say include **Vehicle_Website.App_Code** in the aspx.cs which contains the button method.
The only namespace I can see at the top of the page containing the button (Login.aspx).. is namespace **Vehicle_Website.Pages.Account**. Are you suggesting I need to replace one for the other? Otherwise, I am not too sure how i "include" it in my aspx.cs file.

Im not too sure what your suggesting by point number 2. sorry!! 

Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: do u have team viewer?

Comment: Yeah I do have it,

Comment: I am not able to catch ur xact prob if I can see then I can fix it!! is there a possibility?

Comment: find me in fb aravind2109